# upload wistia videos into a contao page

Tags: video, contao, wistia

I need to upload wistia videos into my contao pages. From the documentation, what i understood is to upload the video in wistia site and get the script from there. For eg: from the official site, I found a script like the following,

```
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/pukozq6xf0.jsonp" async></script>`<script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
<span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_pukozq6xf0 popover=true popoverAnimateThumbnail=true" style="display:inline-block;height:169px;width:300px">&nbsp;</span>
```

Is this is the only step required? That is we just need to add the above script code into my html page?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with vistia, so I cannot make any comments on their service. However regarding Contao the only thing you need to do is add `<script>` to the allowed HTML tags in the system settings, in order to be able to add that script via an HTML content element or HTML module.

Keep in mind that this will enable *any* backend user (with sufficient rights) to add `<script>` tags to your site.